SISS package not extracting all records from Api to database
I am trying to move data from Json Rest API to my database. I am using the data flow task with script task as source and OLE DB as destination.
Sample data
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Project A",
    "owner": "User A",
    "status": "Active",
    "listedItems": [
        {"column1": "100", "column2": "1000", "column3": "Type A"},
        {"column1": "200", "column2": "2000", "column3": "Type B"},
        {"column1": "300", "column2": "3000", "column3": "Type C"}
    ]
}

I want to move only the column1 , column2 and column3 data into a database.
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Tab;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
     {
         public override void CreateNewOutputRows()    
         {
             // Specify the security protocol
             System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    
             // Define the API URL
             string apiUrl = "URL"; // Update with your actual API URL
             string apiKey = "apiKey";
    
             try
             {
                 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
                 request.Method = "GET";
                 request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + apiKey;
    
                 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                 {
                     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                     {
                         string jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                         ParseInventoryItems(jsonResponse);
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
             }
         }
    
         private void ParseInventoryItems(string jsonResponse)
         {
             try
             {
                 // Extract inventory items as before
                 string pattern = "\"listedItems\":\\[(.*?)\\]";
                 Match match = Regex.Match(jsonResponse, pattern);
    
                 if (match.Success)
                 {
                     string listedItemsContent = match.Groups[1].Value;
                     var items = listedItemsContent.Split(new string[] { "},{" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    
                     int rowCount = 0;  // Count of rows added
                     foreach (var item in items)
                     {
                         string cleanedItem = item.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Trim();
                         var keyValuePairs = cleanedItem.Split(',');
    
                         Output0Buffer.AddRow();  // Add a new row
    
                         // Initialize values
                         Output0Buffer.column1 = string.Empty;
                         Output0Buffer.column2 = string.Empty;
                         Output0Buffer.column3 = string.Empty;
    
                         // Parse key-value pairs
                         foreach (var pair in keyValuePairs)
                         {
                             var keyValue = pair.Split(':');
                             if (keyValue.Length != 2) continue;
    
                             string key = keyValue[0].Trim().Trim('"');
                             string value = keyValue[1].Trim().Trim('"');
    
                             // Set output buffer values
                             if (key.Equals("column1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                             {
                                 Output0Buffer.column1 = value;
                             }
                             else if (key.Equals("column2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                             {
                                 Output0Buffer.column2 = value;
                             }
                             else if (key.Equals("tcolum3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                             {
                                 Output0Buffer.column3 = value;
                             }
                         }
    
                         rowCount++;  // Increment row count
                                 // Log the current row information
                         
                     }
    
                     // Final log of total rows processed
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Total Rows Processed: {rowCount}");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No listedItems found in JSON response.");
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error parsing inventory items: " + ex.Message);
             }
         }
     }

The above code is only extracting the 1st item in list ("column1": "100", "column2": "1000", "column3": "Type A") How can I get all the items in that list?

I'd recommend avoiding string manipulation like this and treat the response as JSON. Did you try stepping thru your code with the debugger?

Yes, i tried debugger. the data is coming through jsonResponse but i am not able to extract all to the database

The code "if (keyValue.Length != 2) continue; " is to ensure that each string representing a key-value pair is correctly formatted as key:value. ("column1": "100") The keyValue array is created by splitting the string at the colon (:) character in the listedItems

I think you may be going about this the wrong way. Assuming you're on SQL Server 2019+, you can use native JSON handling in the db. You wouldn't even need a Data Flow task here.
First, make sure you're saving your API results to a string variable. Then you can use the following SQL statement to parse out the values you're looking for. In SSIS, you'd adapt the following for use in an Execute SQL Task.
Using your JSON response as an example, I came up with this:
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Project A",
    "owner": "User A",
    "status": "Active",
    "listedItems": [
        {"column1": "100", "column2": "1000", "column3": "Type A"},
        {"column1": "200", "column2": "2000", "column3": "Type B"},
        {"column1": "300", "column2": "3000", "column3": "Type C"}
    ]
}'

SELECT b.* 
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
    WITH 
        (listedItems NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) AS a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.listedItems) 
    WITH
        (
            column1 INT N'$.column1'
            ,column2 INT N'$.column2'
            ,column3 NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.column3'
        ) AS b

If you adapted this for use in an Execute SQL Task, you could use the SELECT statement as part of a table insert directly into your destination table.
